# Algorithm of HDR viewer of GIMP, Photoshop or anything similiar

Tags: gimp, 8-bit, hdrimages

I am in search of an algorithm capable of displaying an HDR image on an 8-bit screen. Essentially, I require an algorithm that converts HDR to LDR. Specifically, I am aiming to achieve results comparable to those produced by GIMP or Photoshop. I have attempted to locate this algorithm within the GIMP source code, but unfortunately, my search has proven unsuccessful. I prefer a plain algorithm.

Comment: Have a look at GNOME/babl https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/babl

Comment: What you’re looking for is called “tone mapping”, and searching for “tone mapping libraries” will turn up a wealth of resources.

Comment: I don't know why you look at Gimp because AFAIK there is no such thing in Gimp. Gimp can increase contrast and apply various kinds of sharpening, but  If you real tone-mapping with open-source software look at LuminanceHDR.